# Overloading += in c++

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

If I've overloaded operator+ and operator= do I still need to overload 
operator+= for something like this to work:

```
MyClass mc1, mc2;
mc1 += mc2;
```

Comment: Try it and see for yourself.  This is an incredibly quick test.

Comment: It' easy to gain empirical results, but there is a times you still need some explanation.

Comment: @Artem sure, _sometimes_, in this case it won't even compile and does not concern intricate features of language semantics - just pick any reference on C++, it'll tell you enough about operators overloading

Answer (score 8, accepted):

operator+= is not a composite of + and =, therefore you do need to overload it explicitly, since compiler do not know to build puzzles for you. but still you do able to benefit from already defined/overloaded operators, by using them inside operator+=.

Answer (score 26):

Yes, you need to define that as well.

A common trick however, is to define `operator+=`, and then implement `operator+` in terms of it, something like this:

```
MyClass operator+ (MyClass lhs, const MyClass& rhs){
  return lhs += rhs;
}
```

If you do it the other way around (use + to implement +=), you get an unnecessary copy operation in the += operator which may be a problem i performance-sensitive code.

Comment: Old, I know, but it's better just to take `lhs` by value instead of doing the copy manually.

Comment: @GMan: You're right. Wonder why I didn't do this the first time around. Consider it fixed. :)

Comment: @jalf: And if you want to be really terse, `return lhs += rhs;`. :)

Comment: @GMan: pf, now you're just showing off. It's not fair to correct my code right now. I'm busy panicking over my masters' thesis! Can't expect me to write sensible code at the moment! ;) (Also, fixed)

Comment: @GMan: IIRC, I was once shown that `return lhs += rhs;` might be a pessimization, since it's harder for the compiler to figure out that `+=` returns `lhs`, which makes it hard to apply RVO. That was ten years ago and maybe compilers are clever enough to do this, but I will cling to `lhs += rhs; return lhs;` just in case. And, @jalf, Good luck with that!

Comment: @jaif, when overloading operator '+' and passing arguments like you said, 'MyClass operator+(MyClass lhs, const MyClass& rhs)' the compiler(gcc in centos) giving me error --> 'MyClass MyClass::operator+(Counter, const Counter&)' must take either zero or one argument. Why is it?

Comment: @kaushik: because you're doing it wrong. You can either define `operator+` as a member function in which case it takes one parameter (the other parameter is implicitly `this`), or (more commonly) you can define it as a free (non-member) function, which takes two parameters. You're trying to define it as a member function taking two parameters, which makes no sense. :)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you do.

Answer (score 2):

If the real question here is, "I don't want to write a load of repetitive operators, please tell me how to avoid it", then the answer may be:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/utility/operators.htm

The syntax looks a little fiddly, though. As I've never used it myself, I can't reassure you that it's simple really.